# Captureing Image And Printing dat in desired Size

Tags: printing, capture

I want to capture a image from a web cam and i want to print dat captured image in desired size.

Answer (score 0):

consider taking a screenshot programatically and cropping it. if this is not possible, you should talk to the hardware directly by using the driver.

also please provide more info on os, webcam make and programming platform,